# Rails - how to validate one field against another for dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think this is a simple question. In my app, I have a model where users select a 'start' date and a 'stop' date when submitting a new record. The dates are only the years, excluding month and day.

I just want to write a validation to ensure that the stop date is greater than the start date, so you can't submit something that started in 2012 and ended in 2008. How would I do that?

My form fields are below:

```
<%= select_year Date.today, start_year: Time.now.year, end_year: Time.now.year - 95, field_name: :start %>

<%= select_year Date.today, start_year: Time.now.year, end_year: Time.now.year - 95, field_name: :stop %>
```

Comment: Aside from the answers below, consider swapping the values if someone puts in an end smaller then a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do a server side validation, you could add validation to your model

```
validate :stop_date


def stop_date
  errors.add(:stop, "stop date cannot be older than start date") if stop < end
end
```

You could populate the errors on the view.

Comment: I think the implication here is that you'b be better off testing this on input with some javascript.  :)

Comment: Thanks I agree. I am using the client side validations gem so I will try to figure out how to use that for a javascript validation